# AccessViolationException occurred in AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll

Tags: .net, visual-c++, ffmpeg, access-violation, aforge

I have a camera class, in this class I used a timer and in its tick event I am saving video using `AForge.Net`'s VideoFileWriter in C++/Cli (x86, .net framework: v4.6).
This is not supposed to happen, as this is managed code. But even if I wrap in try catch block, program crashes because of `AccessViolationException`. I have verified that Image is not null. Something to do with `VideoFileWriter`. This happens anytime between app start to 30 minutes of running.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll
>   Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

In Visual Studio's output I see

> Exception thrown at 0x0C4D689F (swscale-2.dll) in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x09F83D80.
>   Exception thrown: 'System.AccessViolationException' in
>   AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll

code:

```
 private: System::Void Video_Recorder_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::Timers::ElapsedEventArgs^  e)
  {
      Bitmap^ save = ConvertMatToBitmap(image); //function to convert opencv's Mat to .net's Bitmap        
      if(writer!= nullptr)
       writer->WriteVideoFrame(save);
       delete save;
   }

  VideoFileWriter ^writer = gcnew VideoFileWriter();

  private: Void load_VideoWriter()
  {
    writer->Open("C:/video.avi", 640, 480, 10, VideoCodec::Default);        
  }
```

Visual Studio showed few values for `writer`

> BitRate 400000
>   Codec Default
>   FrameRate 10
>   Height 480
>   IsOpen true
>   Width 640

Let me know if anybody needs more info.
call stack didn't help much

[image]

To my surprise no one on internet is having this issue!
Code seems straight forward, what could possibly be the issue?

Comment: I have the same issue in C#. Maybe it's a bug in the lib? I haven't found solution yet.

Answer (score 3):

Specify the codec as AForge.Video.FFMPEG.VideoCodec.MPEG4 and that error should go away.

Comment: This one did the trick for me, thanks! In my case, I was getting the bitmap from a MemoryStream, and I had set the codec to H264. Would you please tell us (if you know) why MPEG4 doesn't throw, as opposed to other codecs? Thanks again

Comment: @Pona bruh, I don't even remember using this library